# Is it necessary to delete an ever increasing variable? Specifically in game dev with an update loop

Tags: javascript

With a game loop and an infinitely increasing variable, is it necessary for me to delete this variable?

I am using `phaser.js` to create a game and it has a built in game loop (update) and within this update function I have a function that contains an ever increasing number `x * delta`. From my understanding, even if this is within the closure of the function, it will be an ever increasing number.  My question is 2 fold, is it necessary for me to delete this variable (if it will cause lag) and 2, is it possible to delete a variable?

```
function update(delta) {
    playerMovement(delta);
}
```

```
function playerMovement (delta) {
    let gainVelocity = function() {
        let increaseSpeed = 0.25 * delta; //do I need to delete this var?
        if (SPEED > increaseSpeed) {
            return increaseSpeed;
        }
        else {
            return SPEED;
        }
    }

    if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(Math.max(-SPEED, -gainVelocity()));
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(Math.min(SPEED, gainVelocity()));
    }
    else {
        player.setVelocityX(0);
    }
}
```

My thoughts were that I could just change the variable to zero once the function has finished in the else statement, but i'm not sure this would work (I will need to call this function every time I start moving, not sure this will affect my idea of changing the variable).

Comment: What do you mean by "delete a variable"?

Comment: `increaseSpeed` is a local variable inside `gainVelocity`. There's no closure there. It won't keep increasing since it doesn't keep state between calls.

Comment: Well, if I console log it within the function and call the function it always increases... I want to "delete" the variable or in other words, if it will cause lag i want to break the loop of the ever increasing number

Comment: What loop? There is no loop in your code.

Comment: Within phaser (a js game engine) the "update" function is called 60 frames per second.

Comment: @KennethBoelter the ever increasing number (data size) is unlikely the cause of "lag", which heavy computations usually account for. I would recommend you to do profiling your game carefully to figure out what the exact bottleneck is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, there is no point to delete that `increaseSpeed`, JS has garbage collection (GC), for every GC cycle, unused data will be cleaned up, in your case, that would be `gainVelocity` and its internal variables such as `increaseSpeed` after every `update` called
2. There is a `delete` statement in JS, but it is for deleting properties of an object, so it's not applicable to your concern.
3. Primitive data such as string and number in JS is passed by value, so it basically assigns `VelocityX` to a value of zero, and does not impact on the return values of `gainVelocity` or `increaseSpeed`.